# HTML header align content to center

Tags: html, css

```html
<h4 class="modal-title" id="PublishTitle" style="vertical-align: central;"><img id="PublishTitleImage" style="width:35px; height:35px; border-radius: 6px;" src="" /> bla bla</h4>
```

So i want both the image and text to be vertical aligned to center, but it doesnt seem to work, both get aligned to top.

I read that vertical-align: central; is suppose to work, but no?

Comment: Your question contains so little information that I can't find out to which question it is a duplicate, but if you tried `vertical-align: central;`, at least show how.

Comment: It is `vertical-align: middle;`, not `vertical-align: central;`. Don't know where you read that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- the value for `vertical-align` is `middle`, not `center` (and absolutly not `central`)
- You need to set this to the image, not the heading

```css
img {
  width:35px; 
  height:35px; 
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<h4 class="modal-title" id="PublishTitle"><img id="PublishTitleImage" src="" /> bla bla</h4>
```

Comment: bah ninja'd. But you don't need line-height though.

Answer (score 1):

> Try this CSS

```css
.modal-title{position:absolute;top:40%;left:0;right:0;display:table;margin:0 auto}
```

```html
<h4 class="modal-title" id="PublishTitle" style="vertical-align: central;"><img id="PublishTitleImage" style="width:35px; height:35px; border-radius: 6px;" src="" /> bla bla</h4>
```